# No icon in task bar

Tags: c#, wpf, icons, taskbar

I have default settings for application icon, it appears normally in title window  [image: in title], alt-tab menu, explorer, etc. but in taskbar it is shown like this:

[image: in taskbar]

How to fix this and get normal icon in taskbar?

Comment: Are you running it through the debugger? When you run an application through VS's debugger it shows the generic app icon, unless you add it as an icon to the individual windows.

Comment: Set the Icon property to your own custom .ico file under Project Properties->Application->Icon and Manifest in Visual Studio.

Comment: The problem is still present even if I don't use the debugger.

Comment: mm8, I do not want a custom icon, I'm ok with standard one.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the windows and select the Properties and apply the icon like the image

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help

Comment: What didn't help? Specifying your own custom Icon?

Comment: Yes. I specified the custom and still see no icon in taskbar. Moreover, I do not want a custom icon, I'm fine with the standard one.

Answer (score 0):

One of my problems was related to loginDialog. It is possible to get an icon in taskbar using custom icon, but still problem with standard icon is present.

```
        var loginDialog = new LoginView();

        loginDialog.Loaded += (sender, args) => {
            var window = loginDialog.ParentOfType<Window>();
            if (window != null) {
                window.ShowInTaskbar = true;
                window.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/App;component/Themes/MainIcon.png"));
            }
        };
```